# curl: (35) SSL connect error, NSS error -5938

Tags: curl, centos

Hi I am sending an get request using curl but getting error:  curl: NSS error -5938, (35) SSL connect error
Server detail : Centos, version 6.7

curl 'https://govapps.gov.ca.gov/gov39mail/index.php' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'Cache-Control: max-age=0' -H 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36' -H 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br' -H 'Accept-Language: en-GB,en;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,es;q=0.7' -H 'Cookie: GovMail_Session=au0fcpe9hudqgr2773jrpn7jqi; __utmc=158387685; __utmz=158387685.1535521230.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); __utma=158387685.1009969492.1535521230.1536342020.1536345121.9; __utmt_b=1; __utmb=158387685.1.10.1536345121' --compressed -v

- About to connect() to govapps.gov.ca.gov port 443 (#0)
- Trying 134.186.207.137... connected
- Connected to govapps.gov.ca.gov (134.186.207.137) port 443 (#0)
- Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
- CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
- NSS error -5938
- Closing connection #0
- SSL connect error
  curl: (35) SSL connect error

can anyone help me why I am getting this.

Comment: Usually it is linked to an older openssl library that do not support cipher server provides. Can you update your server ?

Comment: Thank you for your response, No I can not there is lots of dependency, is there any other solution?

Comment: I have just noticed that it is working for other url but not for this one.

Comment: Other url has not the same SSL policy. It is really a mismatch between your curl / openssl version (and libraries between) that do not accept 2018 best cipher, and this particular server that only support those cipher.  Other domain may or may not support more cipher. Only way to fix that: update (or possibly upgrade up to 6.10).

Comment: Thanks you for your response I appreciate it. I have updated the dependencies and now it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

It is a mismatch between your curl / openssl version (and libraries between) that do not accept 2018 best cipher, and this particular server that only support those cipher.

Other domain may or may not support more cipher and so curl may (or not) be able to query them.

Only way to fix that: update (or possibly upgrade up to 6.10).

In the future, this can happen again if security increase again.